Does the 15 minute city concept have an answer to the two body problem?
The 15 minute city is defined by wikipedia as:

The 15-minute city (15mC) is an urban planning concept in which most daily necessities and services, such as work, shopping, education, healthcare, and leisure can be easily reached by a 15-minute walk, bike ride, or public transit ride from any point in the city.

The two body problem, when used to refer to academic careers, relates to the issue that most people live with someone else who has a different job to them.  It has in the past frequently been resolved by wives who supported their husbands' careers by interrupting their own which has contributed to inequality in the workplace.
This seems to present a particular challenge to the 15mC concept if "work" in the definition above has to mean two different workplaces.  It seems to be likely that many more people could be affected by this problem that has in the past been more associated with academics.
I have looked at the abstract at least of number of documents that discuss the concept, none seem to address this issue.
Has the problem that getting employment for two people with different specialised careers within 15 minutes is a challenging problem been addressed in the literature?

most daily necessities and services. I do not think people take it as a complete and closed solution and also not universal (so for all people). And the two body problem is real also on modern cities (a city is not enough to solve the problem).

@GiacomoCatenazzi The real world requires that for most people a city is enough to solve the problem, because most households have two people that work in the same city.  I am certainly not arguing the current setup is perfect in this respect, I am sure this effect contributes to inequality in the workplace currently.

Not for academia: a city (few universities) are not enough to find good job for careers for two people. But for most case you can find job nearby (without having the Taxi mom so inequality). Working from home may really help.

@GiacomoCatenazzi Indeed, but the 15 minute city is supposed to apply to everyone.  Few people on minimum wage have the economic power for intercity communes or work within 15 minutes of a partner to be possible.

Sorry, no. If you do not like it, do not look for it. It is not a solution for everyone. Like suburbs: it is a choice, a way to think living. Not Kibbutz (and in any case they have a lot of trade). It is convenience for most of people (money, time and quality of life), but waste management can not be done within 15 min. Water same, Electricity same. We depend on seafarers (many are US citizens) who are months away from home. You cannot growth all foods within 15 minutes. There is no universal solution. Suburbs are financially bad. Let's each people decide.

15mC can't solve everything for everyone in one fell swoop, it's not a silver bullet. For full sustainability we would have to do away with capitalism itself, which in turn could make many such big-city problems evaporate. Like if we ensured full employment via everyone working part-time in multiple types of jobs so there are no longer "underclasses" only ever doing "dirty" jobs, the whole equation changes. If we manage to once again live in multi-generational households and do away with the capitalist overuse of the "nuclear family" model with overburdened parents, again that might solve it.

All I can offer is 15 minutes (bus/bike/walk) to a mainline train station with links to the other person's city, optionally working on the train.  This has similarities with my own situation.  In short, no.

I think you misunderstand the "15 minute city" goal.
The idea is that everyone lives within 15 minutes of their main daily needs, many will work within the 15 minute zone, but it accepts/expects that many people will travel or work outside the 15 minute circle. This is hopefully obvious with academic jobs, but applies more broadly. Think about industrial facilities, transport hubs, even concert halls. The 15 minute city people aren't saying everyone should live within 15 minutes walk from an internatonal airport, let alone a steel foundry.
The goal is that larger city (more than 30 minutes walk from side to side) are supported by excellent public transport at various scales. In simplest form you have a "central station" where people interchange between intercity rail, commuter rail, light rail and buses, the smaller hubs within the city mostly lacking the intercity rail, right down to single stops on the commuter rail (or commuter trams if you're in Melbourne) where there may only be a bus stop. You need radial and circumferential rail, so people can move around the outside of the city rather than always going into the centre then back out.
I live in Sydney, Australia, where we have a setup like that where the public transport is fairly good so an awful lot of people live within 15 minutes walk from a railway station, and most of the rest are within 10 minutes walk from a bus stop. There's local shopping for most people (I'm ~30 minutes from the CBD by train but 10-15 minutes walk from both a high street and a mall). There's everything from GPs to schools to car repair places within 15 minutes walk. Those all employ people as well as providing local services.
Sydney suffers from the train system being radial, and the "central" business district being almost on the eastern edge, but despite that the trains are quite full going out from the CBD during the morning rush. Just not as full as the ones going in. People still choose to commute long distances, generally by train. I've lived in share houses with people who took the train then a bus to get to a university on the other side of town, preferring an hour commute to paying 3x the rent.
In smaller cities "everyone within 15 minutes" can be done, but it rarely is unless there's a physical constraint (an island, for example). Small places more often have cheap land making sprawl to the edge of public transport attractive. Sydney is like that on a big scale - our "suburban" train network covers an area larger than The Netherlands, so people live semi-rurally more than two hours from the city but commute to work in the CBD by train. Or go to concerts, see medical specialists, visit family, attend university... whatever they need to travel for.

Actually, the two body problem is, especially in academics, more about two people having the same job. If you meet as undergrads who are interested in speciality A of faculty B, while doing undergrad work in B, and then become a couple while each doing grad work in A, you will find yourselves both wanting a job as "professor of A" and most universities never hire two such professors in the same year. A couple who managed to solve this problem by getting jobs at the same university would presumably choose a home near campus and be done with that problem.
Yes, there may be a problem where the people involved have different but very specialized jobs. One can only work on a university campus and another only at a hospital. (Those do exist near each other of course, University of Toronto is an example, but they don't do so consistently.) One can only work in a car factory and the other only in a legislature, or a mine, or an air traffic control tower. This is not a failure of the 15 minute city concept. The vast majority of people will have all their needs met within a short distance from their home. A few outliers will have to go further. That could be someone like me traveling 2 (some people travel 4!) hours to the oncologists running the world-changing life-saving study they are in, or someone with a job that can only be done in a very remote area, or someone who doesn't like living near a lot of people and is willing to take on extra commute and errand time to live away from others.
I think most people would be very happy to have their homes be close to every non-work thing anyone in the family needed day to day (school, shopping, doctor, dentist, park, library, entertainment, ...) and be close to one person's work, and the other person still have a commute. That is so much better than each person having a 30-60 minute commute (possibly in different directions), needing to own two cars (and the space to park them), and the services being spread all over town in different directions, no park or library near enough to walk to with kids, etc. That it falls short for some families meaning one person still has the "old fashioned" commute doesn't mean it fails as a concept or isn't worth pursuing.
Also, lives change over time. I've lived in the countryside, far from everything and having to drive, for over 30 years. I intend to retire to a neighbourhood where I can walk to everything I need day to day and week to week, and use transit for the every-few-months things. Not only are there families without conflicting job-location-requirements, there are families without jobs at all who need to be considered in town planning :-)

From what I've seen, the 2nd paragraph is very often the case - a couple working in similar or even quite different - anyway not identical - fields. They then find that suitable research groups/non-academic employers don't  exist in the same city, and if they did, the people would be far from their family (who they may only see a couple of times a year - OK, or may rely on for childcare - problem)

There's nothing suggesting that the two roommates in this example can't work within 15 minutes of each other. A city or town in which everything is reachable via a 15 minute walk or bike ride would still be at least four square kilometers, which while quite small, is still more than large enough for multiple businesses to operate in. And a city in which everything is within a 15 minute ride on public transportation would be even bigger, at least ten square kilometers!

The 15mC isn't about everything being within 15 minutes, just some instance of everything you need. You would have at least some hospital, pizza place, bank etc. no matter where you live. You might still need to move if you want to get a new job, or attain a particular kind of education.

@EdvinW's right, but remember it's a model rather than a real goal. For example the proper hospital (rarely used) may be further away if day-to-day health services can be provided locally at a doctors' surgery or walk-in clinic
